# Display Database Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, json

I am using Ionic 2 calling a RESTful Service (JSON) in Java and a MySQL database. I am trying to display an image that is stored in the database, and render it in ionic.

Everything works perfectly, except I am struggling to get an image to display.

I have a PNG image stored in MySQL (type LONGBLOB). Then I access it, and in **Java**, convert it to Base64.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
subCategory.setIcon(Base64.encodeBase64(subCategory.getIcon()));
```

**JSON:**

```
"icon" : "Vm0wd2QyUXlVWGxWV0d4V1YwZDRWMVl3Wk...lpRVVQwOQ=="
```

Then once received via JSON, I display it in **html**:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{item.icon}}" />
```

It just displays the image placeholder with no image.

I have also tried to decode the image with this **Javascript**:

```
icon = atob(icon);
```

and

```
 b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}
```

with no success.

Comment: What's wrong with `<img src="some url here" />` and setting up an HTTP server that serves image data from MySQL? Aside: Base64 and `decodeURIComponent` are entirely unrelated; one is not the inverse of the other.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the advise. I can then remove `decodeURIComponent`. The reason I have it stored in the database is so that I can add images by just updating the database. Second, I want to keep it simple, the reason why I don't serve them as http, is because I have RESTful JSON services, and am making a call to get rest of the data anyway, I don't want to make another http call.

Comment: ps, removing the `decodeURIComponent` makes no differece, i.e. the image still does not display.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.*

Comment: Hi Ares, thanks for your feedback. The link I posted has a thorough description of my problem.

Comment: @Richard please _don't_ just post a link to somewhere else. When that link rots your question will have lost all context. That's why we want folks to ask the question **in full** here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Apologies, will do

Comment: If I hard-code an image in the html, it works, but when I get one from the database it doesn't display. I guess that suggests there is a problem with my database or java encoding or Json conversion.  e.g. `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{item.icon64}}" />
```

and

```
  b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(atob(str), function(c) {
        return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
}
```

Comment: Strange, it worked, now it doesn't with no code change. Confused! I have cleared browser cache.

Comment: My source code is displaying the following:

`<img ng-reflect-src="data:image/png;base64,Vm0wd2QyUX...M5" src="data:image/png;base64,Vm0wd2QyUX...M5">`
Why is it displaying the `src` twice.

using the following html code:

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{item.icon64}}" />`